# Getting wifi to work on a fresh mint 18 install

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, troubleshooting

I just installed mint and it doesn't show wireless connections, the driver is ticked on.

Also when I try to do `rfkill list` nothing show up.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Maybe I need to get the drivers for this laptop somehow?

I did make sure that the wifi is on in this laptop (HP G62), I also just had an ubuntu install and wifi worked there right from the start.

Edit:

`lspci -nn | grep 0280` output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3090]
```

Edit2:

To make it even more strange, when I load the live usb version, I do get wifi networks to show up at the bottom...

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of running this command in a terminal: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`.

Answer (score -1):

I did a complete erase and reinstall and ticked the "install third party stuff" this time and now it works.

Maybe it happened because I had ubuntu before installing mint over it.

I hope mint won't try to burn my laptop with 100% CPU all the time like ubuntu did.